# how do I find and remove sublime text 4 update file that was downloaded without confirmation when I clicked "check for updates"

Tags: sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text 3, and made the mistake of clicking "check for updates" which downloads an update file with no confirmation about what version will be downloaded, and no information about the update file name or location.

Rather than simply presenting a dialog such as "you have the latest version of Sublime Text 3, but Sublime Text 4 is available" it just downloads version 4. (I discovered this the hard way over a year ago when I naively assumed Sublime's updater would behave in a responsible fashion and present a dialog before downloading an entirely new version my license doesn't support. But I forgot and clicked check update again.)

Where can I find and delete the v4 update file that was downloaded? ("Recents" under Finder does not show any new files so I assume it's hidden in some Library or cache folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it on another site.

The update downloaded by Sublime Text 3 is not a file, it's a folder named "Update" in:

~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3